# I have a managed assembly and need to debug it but can't

Tags: c#, .net, debugging, ollydbg

I have an .exe which is a portable program. It is assembled with Microsoft Visual C# / Basic .NET 
I managed to find out that in order OllyDBG to be able to open it, it should be running and also JIT compiler producing some code. I am a beginner and not at all understand the full process. When it's running, it doesn't create any other files near it ( though when laucnhing the installable version it creates a temporary .dat file aside it). But the portable version is the same size so I am working with it. 
 While it is running, anyway the debugger can't open it ( nor the installed version )... So my question is - what am I missing in order to make it readable. I just need to make a small change in the .exe but I cannot get into it. Please help me with few more details to make it happen.

Comment: You need the PDB symbol files that are created when you build in debug mode (or have `Generate Debug Info` turned on).

Answer (score 0):

If it really is a managed application built with a .NET compiler, then the assembly program is actually composed of [IL code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Intermediate_Language), which can more or less be reverted back into source code for you to modify. In order to do this, you can use a tool such as [ILSpy](http://ilspy.net/) or [.NET Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/reflector/).

There is a possibility that the assembly may have some kind of obfuscation to discourage decompilation, and in that case, you will need either look to the developer of the software for permission, or to a specialized deobfuscation program like [de4dot](https://github.com/0xd4d/de4dot).

Keep in mind, *the terms of service of the application may forbid you from modifying the assembly*, but this isn't a legal advice forum.

Comment: Very nice description, Patrick. I am a step closer to understanding the logics of all this. In a few words - The site that had a kind of physical products selling, has closed last year. There is no assistance and no one to talk to about it. So, last year I have used their device for scanning certain digital information and save it in a file format that only their program can read ( the same program I am having now) There is no fee to have the program. There is only the price of the device which can be bought. 
Now, I have changed my computer since than and also sold my device. When trying to

Comment: When trying to open the file I saved, the program is asking for a key, which I don't have anymore. Now the only thing I need is open the file ( but the key is related only to the serial number of the device. So what I need is to remove the part of key asking and just open my ilst. The key is not related to the file, only to the sof , which wants to know I am still having that code from the back of the device.

Comment: It asks for it only at the first opening of the file, and offers it to be saved for further usage of the program. Thats the tiny part I need to get reed of...

Comment: SO I found a tutorial explaning how to do this, but the funny part is that OllyDBG can't open the file in its condition.

Comment: Looking at OllyDBG, it doesn't surprise me that it doesn't open a managed applicaton. You'll need a managed disassembler if the application is managed. You'll have a hard time finding people on StackOverflow that will help you with what you're trying to accomplish, as it's essentially cracking software (albeit for personal reasons). I wish you luck on getting access to your files back. In conclusion, look into ILSpy and research IL code.

Comment: You *can* debug a .NET assembly with OllyDbg, it just shows you the assembly code generated by the JIT compiler. Visual Studio's debugger makes this even easier. But your answer is otherwise correct that there's no real reason to do so when you can inspect the IL instead.

Comment: Is IL able to compile back a working exe? I am looking for a debugger because I need to see what DLL is being triggered when the key is prompted. IL can handle such thing?

Comment: @CodyGray That's very interesting, wasn't aware it could debug the JIT code.

Comment: @MangoPolo Some disassemblers do allow for modifications to the IL and recompilation (read: not all of them). Some even allow you to export the project into a .sln project. Also, if you found my answer helpful, please go ahead and accept it as the correct answer :)